# Fill panel when there are two i identifiers and one t time

Tags: stata

I have panel data with two individual identifiers and one time identifier (calendar years). Each `year` there are different combinations of the individuals that I will call `gym` and `teacher`. I provide toy data below.

I would like to fill out the data so that each `year` I have every combination of `gym` and `teacher` that exist elsewhere in that year. That is, if `gym` and `teacher` exist anywhere in the `year` I would like to include them as a new combination in the panel. Then I will fill in their `classes` variable with 0.

If I `egen group()` these two identifiers I can create a combination identifier `gt` that allows me to `xtset` and use `tsfill, full` to complete the panel. Again, code below.

My problem is that if a gym and teacher are never together, then they aren't part of `gt` and don't get filled. I'm not sure what is the solution. Is there a way to generate every combination of `gym` and `teacher` and then `xtset` and `tsfill` on that? Or a better approach all together? Thanks.

```
clear
input gym teacher year classes
1   1   2001    1
1   2   2001    1
1   3   2001    1
2   1   2001    1
2   2   2001    1 
1   1   2002    1
1   2   2002    1
2   1   2002    1   
2   2   2002    1
2   3   2002    1
1   1   2003    1
1   2   2003    1
3   1   2003    1
end

* one option, `tsfill, full`
egen gt = group(gym teacher)
xtset gt year
tsfill, full

/* fill missing gyms, teachers, classes */
bysort gt (gym): replace gym = gym[1] if missing(gym)
bysort gt (teacher): replace teacher = teacher[1] if missing(teacher)
bysort gym year: egen N = count(classes)
drop if (N == 0)
drop N
bysort teacher year: egen N = count(classes)
drop if (N == 0)
drop N

/* gym 1 should exist all 3 years */
/* gym 2 should exist 2001 and 2002 */
/* gym 3 should exist 2003, only */
/* all teachers in 2001 and 2002 */
/* teachers 1 and 2, only, in 2003 */
table gym teacher year

/* I'm missing gym 3, teacher 2 combination, because they don't exist any where in the sample, but they could have existed. */
```

Comment: I can't see a point to fake data for combinations that don't exist. In any case, what would you impute?

Comment: I would impute zero. If the gym and teacher are in the sample that year, then they could have paired (the real context is a little different). I agree that imputing a zero is a little odd, this is just robustness with a censored (Tobit) model. It isn't that they gym doesn't know about the teacher, it is that they chose to have them teach zero classes.

Comment: OK. Checkout `fillin`.

Comment: @NickCox -- That does it. Thank you. I will post an answer for posterity (if you'd like the cred, then please cut/paste/edit and I'll accept your version).

Comment: Thanks. I never turn down increased reputation....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout `fillin`. In addition to the usual documentation, a chatty introduction is accessible in [this Stata Journal Tip](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0011)

Answer (score 0):

@NickCox was correct in the comments above. This feature exists in Stata as the `fillin` command. After I `fillin` on `gym`, `teacher`, and `year` I `bysort` on combinations to make sure that `gym` or `teacher` exist elsewhere in the same `year`. If they don't exist in that year, then I drop that combination.

```
fillin gym teacher year
bysort gym year: egen N1 = count(classes)
bysort teacher year: egen N2 = count(classes)
drop if (N1 == 0) | (N2 == 0)
table gym teacher year
```

Yields.

```
. table gym teacher year

--------------------------------------------------------------------
          |                     year and teacher                    
          | ----- 2001 -----    ----- 2002 -----    ----- 2003 -----
      gym |    1     2     3       1     2     3       1     2     3
----------+---------------------------------------------------------
        1 |    1     1     1       1     1     1       1     1      
        2 |    1     1     1       1     1     1                    
        3 |                                            1     1      
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```